# Why is this jQuery code not getting parsed?

Tags: jquery

Can someone take a look inside [this script](http://www.tapet-online.ro/skin/frontend/default/acumen/js/manatln.js) and tell me why isn't it parsed, triggered and active?
I mean, everything I put after `(function($) {` has no effect.

That script should've dropped down a filtering menu's elements from a category page. ( ie: [this one](http://www.tapet-online.ro/catalog/fototapet.html) )

I really don't know what to do here. I've tried several things and I haven't found a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, put your js code in jsbin or jsfiddle!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: When is this function called? Those elements may not be available yet? Please add more to your question

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of JS errors on your example page. It looks like jQuery is simply missing from the page itself.

Comment: His jquery include (v1.7.1) is returning 404.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `live` method doesn't exist any more since jQuery 1.9. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live is depracted and removed from jquery in the latest release

Comment: Oh, it is true. I've deleted another folder which contained jQuery. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discoved the error - I've deleted another folder which contained the jQuery file.